# Unwanted validation of synonym to remote table at compile time - SQL2K8 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server, synonym

I'm working in an environment where data exists on numerous client databases and one by one is pulled into a central data repository via sql.

To automate a testing process, I've written a really nice, streamlined push-button script that backups, purges and re-extracts data on a user-specified client database. Change a few parameters and hit run and it just works. The script will be handed off to semi-technical staff so simplicity is a must.

I have one problem though. The script makes heavy use of dynamically generated synonyms that map to remote tables via a linked server. A few of these tables are backup tables created by the script.

What I'm discovering is, if one of the script-created backup tables is dropped (or the database copy is refreshed overnight) while the synonym to the backup still exists on the central server, the script will fail with the following error:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "[linkedservername]"
>   does not contain the table
>   ""[database_name]"."[schema_name]"."[backup_table_name]"". The table
>   either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on
>   that table.

At compile time, SQL Server is checking behind each synonym referenced in the script for a valid destination object (table). Is there a way to prevent SQL Server from doing this, similar to how stored procedures no longer require database objects to exist in order to be created?

Note that I do have a flag that determines whether or not to drop synonyms at the end of the script to make debugging/investigations easier, that is why these synonyms may sometimes remain on the server. However, the script pre-emptively drops every synonym before creating it to ensure that no leftover synonym is accidentally used.

But because the error occurs at script compile time, it never gets a chance to drop old synonyms. In fact, not a single line of of the script gets executed. So it's not even a case where I could purge all of the synonyms in the beginning of the script.

Is there a way to turn off synonym compilation checking? I would like to keep this a single do-everything script that requires no user intervention or troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't have a pretty solution, but if you stick this all in a dynamic query, it won't check.

Comment: Yea, I thought of that, but the whole point of creating synonyms is to reduce the amount of dynamic sql in the script.